# Travel from South Africa to Croatia via Germany

Tags: visas, schengen, croatia

Need some assistance regarding visa applications. I am travelling to Croatia from South Africa in October and need to get my visa(s) sorted out. I am not sure if I just need to apply for a Croation visa or also a Schengen visa. My itinerary is:

1. Johannesburg to Munich (arrive 07:20)
   (stop over of 4 hours 40 minutes)
2. Munich (depart 12:00) to Zagreb

Return flight similar just via Frankfurt with a 5 hour 25 minute stop over.

I know that with a multiple entry Schengen visa I can enter Croatia without a Croatian visa; however I am not sure that I will be able to obtain a Schengen visa given that I am only doing a stop-over in Germany.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you won't need to enter the Schengen area during your layovers (you can easily stay within the international transit zones of Munich and Frankfurt airports), you would not have a coherent premise for applying for a Schengen visa, and such an application would very likely be refused.

You should apply for a Croatian visa directly from Croatia.